# Sorts the lines alphabetically in a csv txt or any other file

Tags: python, file-io

I need to write a program that prompts the user for any file name, loads the data line by line, removes any duplicate lines, sorts the lines alphabetically, and write the remaining lines to another file.

I am done with most of the code, but I am struggling to sort my lines alphabetically. Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance for your help!

```py
def deleteDuplicateRecords(fileName):
    try:
        newFileName="filtered_"+fileName
        with open(fileName,'r') as readFile, open(newFileName,'w') as writeFile:
            lineSet = set()
            for line in readFile:
                if line not in lineSet: 
                    lineSet.add(line)
                    writeFile.write(line)
        readFile.close()
        writeFile.close()
        print(f"Duplicate rows removed succesfully. Open the new file '{newFileName}'")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File Not Found")

name = input("Enter the name of the text file including the proper extension (.txt, .csv, etc): ")
print()

deleteDuplicateRecords(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def deleteDuplicateRecords(fileName):
    try:
        newFileName="filtered_"+fileName
        with open(fileName,'r') as readFile, open(newFileName,'w') as writeFile:
            for sorted_line in sorted({line for line in readFile}):
                writeFile.write(sorted_line)
        print(f"Duplicate rows removed successfully. Open the new file '{newFileName}'")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File Not Found")
```

Some notes:

1. As mentioned by others, If you use the `with`, this automatically closes the files when the scope is ended.
2. If you use a set, a duplicate item will not be added to the list so there is no reason to check if the item already exists in the list
3. If you have an iterable (list, set, etc), you can simply use the `sorted` function to sort the results
4. The line `{line for line in readFile}` uses [set comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/set_comprehension.html) to create a set from the lines of the file in a more concise way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Accumulate the lines in a set
2. Sort the set with `sorted`, which returns a list
3. **Then** write the lines into the output file

BTW using a with-statement means you don't need to manually close the files.

Answer (score 0):

you can read this Documentation for all sorted method .
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html
after this return sorted to your output .